# How can I test in app purchases if http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ is not working?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app with IAP but I can not test those IAP in sandbox because the servers are down this is what I think.
So is there anyway I can check if I am doing it correctly ?

Comment: If the servers are down, why can't you wait for them to come back up?

Comment: They have been down since december, or maybe before that... I can not wait anymore

Comment: That's a long time for them to be down. Do they not offer any status page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How check sandbox server status? ("Cannot connect to itunes store")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734088/how-check-sandbox-server-status-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734088/how-check-sandbox-server-status-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)  Also, this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) on Validating Receipts lists testing and production URLs for sending requests and status codes returned by the URLs.

For example, try opening [this Apple test URL](https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt) in a browser.  For me, it returned a status code of 21000.  According to the Apple documentation, that means "The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided.", indicating that at least the server is alive and well.